# Annotating certain pages of a pdf in xournal++ (xournalpp)

Tags: pdf, annotation

I'm in the process of type-setting notes for my class this coming semester, and I'd like to annotate these notes using xournal++ (xournalpp). I'll be writing these notes throughout the semester and the resulting .pdf file will end up being rather lengthy. Is it possible to only "import" a range of pages of a .pdf file in xournal++?

Comment: You can first "print" those ranges of pages to a pdf with your pdf reader software (e.g. Evince or Okular) and then open that pdf with Xournal++.